# ARIMA (auto.arima in R) forecasts 0 for high variance and large time series

Tags: r, arima, forecast

I'm noticing an issue with using `auto.arima` in R where if I input a series with large values and high variance, the forecast simply returns 0. Is this because the hyperparameters chosen are wrong? For example, see the simple example below:

```
library(forecast)

my_time_series = c(
  234829874, 
  293481040534,
  4087598324,
  20394823094324,
  234832948234,
  2034982034,
  2304984,
  2039483029481,
  20349812044,
  2034982094814
)
forecast(auto.arima(my_time_series))

>>>
  Point Forecast         Lo 80        Hi 80         Lo 95        Hi 95
11              0 -8.348708e+12 8.348708e+12 -1.276825e+13 1.276825e+13
12              0 -8.348708e+12 8.348708e+12 -1.276825e+13 1.276825e+13
13              0 -8.348708e+12 8.348708e+12 -1.276825e+13 1.276825e+13
14              0 -8.348708e+12 8.348708e+12 -1.276825e+13 1.276825e+13
15              0 -8.348708e+12 8.348708e+12 -1.276825e+13 1.276825e+13
16              0 -8.348708e+12 8.348708e+12 -1.276825e+13 1.276825e+13
17              0 -8.348708e+12 8.348708e+12 -1.276825e+13 1.276825e+13
18              0 -8.348708e+12 8.348708e+12 -1.276825e+13 1.276825e+13
19              0 -8.348708e+12 8.348708e+12 -1.276825e+13 1.276825e+13
20              0 -8.348708e+12 8.348708e+12 -1.276825e+13 1.276825e+13
```

Why is this and how do I fix this? For example, in this fictional time series, I would have expected at least ARIMA to basically output the mean, but I don't understand why it's forecasting 0.

Comment: The best-fit model returned by `auto.arima` in your case is `ARIMA(0,0,0) with zero mean`. The `auto.arima` function considers more complex models and compares them w  AIC/BIC selection criteria, and I believe it settles on the "simplest" possible arima model bc your data varies wildly by many orders of magnitude. If you log transform your series you'd get a model with non-zero mean. You might want to consider heading over to CrossValidated for modeling help if you want to go deeper, because there are no bugs in your code.

Comment: Thanks x-posted here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493396/arima-auto-arima-in-r-forecasts-0-for-high-variance-and-large-time-series

Comment: you should use `forecast(auto.arima(my_time_series, lambda = 0))`, it will log the data. The arima models are designed for stationary time series. And your is not.

Comment: I have given an answer to this question in the cross-posted link. (I don't think this is a programming issue.)